# MySQL: How to get a cell's value from a different row of the same table

Tags: mysql

I apologize for the possible vague/inaccurate title, but I was not sure exactly what to write. Feel free to edit.

I have myself a MySQL table called A.
A has three columns

ID, Parent ID, and Name.

Organization ID is auto-incremented and never null. Parent ID can be null. The name is just A, B, C, D, E, etc.

My question is. When I display the information, instead of displaying the Parent ID, I want to get the parent name instead.

To further explain what I want, consider the following information:

```
ID, PID, NAME:
1,  5,   HELLO
2,  5,   POPPET
3,  5,   HI
4,  5,   BYE
5,   ,   PARENT
6,   ,   LOL
7,  8,   LUL
8,   ,   TROPICAL
```

Should become

```
ID, PID,      NAME:
1,  PARENT  , HELLO
2,  PARENT  , POPPET
3,  PARENT  , HI
4,  PARENT  , BYE
5,          , PARENT
6,          , LOL
7,  TROPICAL, LUL
8,          , TROPICAL
```

Something like that. I'm semi-convinced that the solution is simple, but I am fairly new to MySQL and do not know much about the syntax to do cool things.

It seems overly simple but do I need to join the table with itself? I was thinking of a SELECT on the table with a LEFT JOIN on itself. Is there some way of referencing another row? An easier way perhaps? :)

Any insight is greatly appreciated, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joining the table to itself is exactly what you need to do.  Like so:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t2.NAME, t1.NAME
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t2.ID = t1.PID
```

Answer (score 1):

You were halfway there!

```
SELECT a.ID, p.Name as ParentName, a.Name as ItemName
FROM TableA a LEFT JOIN TableParent p on a.ParentID = p.ID
```